# How to measure the time in simulink when it receives a signal

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a model in matlab simulink .I want to measure the time when a signal is received in the simulink model .Is there any way to find the time .Appreciate if someone could share your knowledge on this .

I could not find any solution for this

Comment: What do you mean "received"? Where is the signal coming from? Have you tried using a `clock` block to output the current simulation time, and using a switch with it to output the time when a certain condition is true?

Comment: It is getting a signal from a python code.

Comment: Without a [mcve] showing what's going on, it's pretty much impossible for us to guess what the solution should be. "Getting a signal from a python code" is way too vague

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the time that took to your Matlab commands you can use Matlab's [tic & toc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html)  commands.

Add `tic` command before the code and `toc` after the code and you will get the time

Example from mathworks site:

```
tic
A = rand(12000,4400);
B = rand(12000,4400);
toc
```

It will print:

> Elapsed time is 0.664779 seconds.

Comment: okay .but this method can be used in a matlab script.
How can we use inside a simulink model